# How to extend a single window across 4 virtual desktops on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-desktop

How can I stretch or span a single window across multiple virtual desktops (four in total).

<sub>I am running Windows 7 and I have tried the Dexpot virtual desktop software</sub>

Answer (score 0):

NVIDIA has a technology that's built-to my quadro 3000 g-card called 'Mosaic'.  It allows multiple monitors to be treated like one.  Not sure about virtual desktops though. Hope that helps.